# how to use python requests to login to website

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

Im trying to login and scrape a job site and send me notification when ever certain key words are found.I think i have correctly traced the xpath for the value of feild "login[iovation]" but i cannot extract the value,   here is what i have done so far to login

```
import requests
from lxml import html
header = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.5;Windows NT)"}
login_url = 'https://www.upwork.com/ab/account-security/login'
session_requests = requests.session()
#get csrf
result = session_requests.get(login_url)
tree=html.fromstring(result.text)
auth_token = list(set(tree.xpath('//*[@name="login[_token]"]/@value')))
auth_iovat = list(set(tree.xpath('//*[@name="login[iovation]"]/@value')))
# create payload
payload = {
    "login[username]": "myemail@gmail.com", 
    "login[password]": "pa$$w0rD", 
    "login[_token]": auth_token,
        "login[iovation]": auth_iovation, 
        "login[redir]": "/home" 
}

#perform login
scrapeurl='https://www.upwork.com/ab/find-work/'
result=session_requests.post(login_url, data = payload, headers = dict(referer = login_url))
#test the result
print result.text
```

This is screen shot of form data when i login successfully
[image]

Comment: run browser without `JavaScript` and check if you see this values - maybe this values are added by `JavaScript` and requests doesn't run `JavaScript`

Comment: Thanks furas , when i disabled javascript the value field for loginp[iovation] disappeared

Comment: can you login without javascript ? On this page I saw file with insteresting name [account-security-ui-combined.js](https://www.upwork.com/ab/account-security/static-assets/js/account-security-ui-combined.js?3482da8?3482da8). Maybe it can help to find this codes. Or you will have to use `Selenium` to control browser which run JavaScript.

Comment: Nope. I'll try to login using beautifulsoup(not sure) or as you suggested selenium

Comment: If page in browser doesn't work (doesn't login) without JavaScript then you could use `Selenium` because it can be easier. BS needs more work analyzing JavaScript before you create useful Python script.

Comment: I would suggest using a tool more suited to scraping, such as [Scrapy](https://scrapy.org/).

Answer (score 1):

This is because upworks uses something called iOvation (https://www.iovation.com/) to reduce fraud. iOvation uses digital fingerprint of your device/browser, which are sent via login[iovation] parameter.

If you look at the javascripts loaded on your site, you will find two javascript being loaded from iesnare.com domain. This domain and many others are owned by iOvaiton to drop third party javascript to identify your device/browser.

I think if you copy the string from the successful login and send it over along with all the http headers as is including the browser agent in python code, you should be okie.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that result is fetching 2XX code

When I am this code `result = session_requests.get(login_url)`..its fetching me a 403 status code, which means I am not going to login_url itself

Answer (score 0):

They have an official API now, no need for scraping, just register for API keys.